# Interact with a webpage containing dynamic list using Python

Tags: python, html, mechanize, todoist

I am trying to write a Python program to automatically add tasks to todoist.  I am currently trying to use mechanize but not sure if this is what I need because it is set up to interact with forms and I'm not sure if todoist is using HTML forms for input.  This is my code so far:

```
import mechanize;
import re;

br = mechanize.Browser();
br.open("http://todoist.com/");
assert br.viewing_html();
print br.title();
print br.forms();
```

Which prints

```
To-do list and task manager. Free, easy, online and mobile: Todoist
<generator object __call__ at 0x02D69288>
```

So it is successfully connecting to todoist but I am not sure how to access the input forms to actually have it put tasks in?  Also not sure why br.forms() prints the reference rather than the value (which is an empty list)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few modules already available that allow me to interface with the todoist API.  This one seems to be working well in case anyone comes searching with the same question:  https://github.com/Garee/pytodoist

Comment: Additionally information on the todoist API is available:  https://todoist.com/API/